# Creating "highlight" like effect on "info dark" button on white background

Tags: iphone

If I put a "info light" button in the lower corner of my screen on dark background and check "Shows Touch On Hightlight", I get a nice highlight effect when the user touches the icon. It gives the user positive feedback.

In my app the background it white. So I selected "info dark" button. The "Shows Touch On Highlight" and "Highlighted Adjusts Image" are checked. But because the background is white, the highlight effect is not visible and the user does not get any feedback.

How can I create some kind of highlight/lowlight like effect to give some feedback to the use then the info button is touched?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: I have figured it out. Create a new image with dark glow called infoDarkHighlighted.png and set the following in the ViewController's viewDidLoad mothod.

[infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"infoDarkHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 1):

The "glow" you see when the button is touched is fixed and cannot be changed.

Your best bet is to write a custom button yourself that provides this glow, but in a dark color.

Comment: I can create a custom button with an image but how do I create a glow effect with dark color?

Comment: While I don't know for sure, I suspect the glow Apple uses is just a PNG faded in and out.