# iOS - UIButton shows touch on highlight color

Tags: ios, colors, uibutton, highlight

i would like to know if is possible to change the color of the glow appears when the showsTouchOnHighlighted option is enabled on a UIButton.
Thanks

Comment: Something similar was resolved here as workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626965/creating-highlight-like-effect-on-info-dark-button-on-white-background

Comment: @Denis good, but he use an image, i want to programmatically change the glow color. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me we can't change color of button. But you can change its image. You can set image for all the button states available.

> **- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state**

Here you can find more details about the same: [*UIButton Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Choose your state as *UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateSelected or UIControlStateHighlighted* as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A image can be create with a UIColor so we need to add something like that:

```
    [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]] 
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

-

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```